# C++ Socket recv call not working as expected

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, wireshark, recv

I am using the below code to read from a non-blocking socket, but occasionally I read 1 byte less than is shown for the same socket on wireshark. For example wireshark could show that the data received has a length of 185 as it should but the recv only gets 184 bytes.

```
int len = 0;
unsigned char buffer[**Twice larger than could be received**]; 
while (1) {
    int rc = recv(sock, buffer+len, sizeof(buffer) - len, 0);
    if (rc < 0) {
        if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK){
            continue;
        }
        break;
     }
     if (rc == 0) {
         break;
     }
     len += rc;
}
```

Comment: What is in that 1 byte that was not read?

Comment: It is random. I thought it had something to do with it, but no.

Comment: `recv` does not work on TCP packets, it works on the socket read buffer. `recv` can return part of a packet, content from multiple packets (in sequence order). TCP provides only a byte stream and not messages.

Comment: It doesn't explain why I get 1 byte less. The crazy thing is, it is consistently 1 byte less, never more than that.

Comment: And when you added the debugging statements that showed exactly what parameters were passed into the `recv()` call, especially the value of the third one, what did you see?

Comment: ¿Does the loop break at `rc == 0` or an error occurs?

Comment: Of course the 3rd parameter is always more than 0 at every iteration.

Comment: And yes, the loop breaks at rc == 0 always. No errno other than EWOULDBLOCK is ever caught.

Comment: Is this the last byte missing or the first byte missing or something in between? If the last byte - what happened then, i.e. did a later retry (i.e. after select/poll signaled socket readable) returned the data or was the connection closed or did you get some error or what? If the first byte - then there was likely some code you don't show which has read this already.

Comment: did u try to comment the rc == 0 break? just for testing

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it is the last byte. And later retries at reading the socket after poll indicated it was readable returned 0 byte on read.

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper commenting out rc == 0 as expected gets the program stuck in an infinite loop because recv always returned 0.

Comment: `**Twice larger than could be received**` : Are you sure? :) What if `sizeof(buffer) - len == 0` and you get 0, not because of TCP FIN but because you pass zero into `recv` function

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko 100% certain. Debugging the loop shows that there is no iteration when `sizeof(buffer) - len ` is ever `0`

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you call `shutdown()` function right after you send 185 bytes? If yes, what if you do not shut down the connection?

Comment: The maximum amount you can receive is defined by the size of the socket receive buffer SO_RCVBUFSIZ. What is that, and what is ‘Twice larger than could be received’? And why are you using non-blocking mode without `select()`?

Comment: @user207421 I am using `poll` but didn't include that part of the code. SO_RCVBUFSIZ is about 208KB and my buffer for recv is just 4KB. By indicating that my buffer for recv is always 2x the size of the data being received. It makes it obvious, that is not the source of the error.

Comment: it looks that what you posted can't help us enough. i guess that posting more code would be helpful, e.g. posting the send call. I m still thinking that the rc == 0 would break the program before to receive the last byte. you would try to add a counter so that once it recv 0 bytes X times it breaks. Once it recv a non 0 count of bytes you have to reset the counter.

Comment: So this isn’t the real code. Post the real code. The real code shouldn't deal with EAGAIN like that. I suggest the real code does `len += rc` when `rc` is -1.

Comment: @user207421 The loop is the real code. What happens before that is socket creation, polling and entering the loop if socket is readable.

Comment: Then you aren't using `poll()` correctly. Instead of pointlessly looping on`EAGAIN` you should be calling `poll()` to tell you when it is next appropriate to read; or returning to your poll loop for ditto.

Comment: @user207421 regardless of does the author use poll/select or not, it does not explain why doesn't the loop read all the bytes.